# How can an app be asking for my iPhone's unlock passcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

This is new, and scary to me, experience.

I wanted to try to use Whatsapp from the web. To do this I was told to open the app on iOS and go to settings->Linked Devices->Link A Device

[image]

And then it asks me to enter my iPhone's unlock code

[image]

I've never seen this behavior before. IIRC the only times I've seen my iPhone ask for me to enter my passcode is (1) to unlock the phone (2) when I double click the right side button to pay and it can't see my face

What is this feature of iOS that lets an app ask for the iPhone's unlock code. What is happening here? Is this Facebook doing something nefarious or is it some special feature of iOS that I've never encountered before.

Comment: This is very much a concern. On the web, it doesn’t take long to see attempts to pop up alerts to phish or steal credentials. Knowing when you’re typing into a trusted process can be very tricky to tell.

Comment: Whatsapp is an unusual app in that it will use your phone to send a message so the desktop has to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

> **iPhone**: **Tap Link a Device** > **OK**. On iOS 14 and above, use Touch ID or Face ID to unlock. If you don’t have biometric authentication enabled, you’ll be prompted to enter the pin you use to unlock your phone.

https://faq.whatsapp.com/web/download-and-installation/how-to-log-in-or-out

Comment: In Settings->Account->Privacy->Screen Lock the only option is "Require Face ID" and it's off

Comment: They have explained in FAQ. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I know that display is actually iOS and not just the app putting up a screen that looks exactly the same and then recording my passcode? The other places I put my passcode in (when unlocking the phone, when I double tap to pay) I know are from the OS since only the OS can respond to those gestures but any app can display something that looks like my lock screen in response to a button in their own app

Comment: In simple words, whenever any program/app wants to verify you, it will call a function & the os will ask for biometric/passcode and if it's correct; the function returns the calling program a True value and the program proceeds further. These sensitive information are stored securely by OS and are not accessible to any program. If you want to test, you can enter wrong passcode and it will fail. That means it's checking the already stored password and only the system function is allowed to do that. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. My point is the app itself can display a fake "enter your passcode" page and then not use the passcode but send it to their servers "passcode for user123 is probably 432432". Ideally the OS should provide some way to verify the screen is the OS passcode screen, not some fake passcode screen. As I said above, the only times I've seen this screen before are on phone unlock and tap to pay and only the OS can respond to those 2 gestures. OTOH hand, any app can put up a fake passcode screen and AFAICT there's no way for a user to tell if it's fake or real.

Comment: I get your point. But if you believe it's a fake prompt by the app, that means the app doesn't already know your password and in that case if you are entering wrong password; it should open with even wrong one as there is no way of validating if it's wrong for a fake pop up.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like anytime a user sees an app present that screen they should first enter a wrong passcode to prove it's the real OS screen. If it fails then it is the OS screen so enter the correct code. If it succeeds on the wrong code then it's a fake screen. Ok, good to know the secure way to handle an app appearing to ask for a passcode